# Using Google's Intelligent Search API (or other name I don't know about)

Tags: android, google-search

E.G. when you search "time in hawaii" in google it automatically gives you the time there.

Is there an available api so we can make queries from inside an application and get those results?

Comment: Have you looked at Google's Freebase API: https://developers.google.com/freebase/

Comment: EXACTLY what i have been looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at Google's Freebase API to see how to get structured data from a knowledge graph in your app.

https://developers.google.com/freebase/index